# Replace all values in a column in SSIS

Tags: ssis

The input column ("Version") has multiple string values but I need to replace all them by a date (1900-01-01).

I am currently trying to do this with the derived column transformation in a data flow object, but it looks like that its imposible.

Source and Destination are Flat Files.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `"1900-01-01"` as the value of your `Version` column, add a `Derived Column Transformation` and just set the value there. Choose `Replace 'Version'` as the `Derived Column` and `"1900-01-01"` as the `Expression`. The configuration looks like this:

[image]

The flat file output will look similar to this, assuming you're inserting into a basic, delimited flat file:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! I can't believe it was that easy. (My workaround was to use a Script Component LOL) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Why is it impossible? Do you get the wrong format, or some error?
Should definately be doable with derived column, by choosing "Replace " instead of "Add as new column" in the derived column dialog. With some expression like:

```
(DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)(GETDATE())
```